# Angular 4 gitlab ci

Tags: javascript, angular2, gitlab

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
>
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

На локале запускаю ошибок нет на сервере такая ошибка после команды

```
$ ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --single-run=true --browsers PhantomJS --watch=false
```

Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

```
at createSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15457:109)
at parseSourceFileWorker (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15389:26)
at Object.parseSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15338:26)
at Object.createSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:15192:29)
at VirtualFileStats.getSourceFile (/front/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:66:35)
at WebpackCompilerHost.getSourceFile (/front/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/compiler_host.js:213:38)
at findSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67909:29)
at processImportedModules (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
at findSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
at processImportedModules (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
at findSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
at processImportedModules (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:68056:25)
at findSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67937:17)
at processSourceFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67840:27)
at processRootFile (/front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67728:13)
at /front/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:67018:60
```

Comment: полный стек ошибки нужен.

Comment: @tcpack4 добавил

Comment: стек не полный. путей первой строчки с ошибкой нет.